# To expose WCF service as asmx(web service) and hosted in window service

Tags: wcf, web-services, visual-studio-2008, wcf-client

I am developing the wcf application in VS2008. I want to host that WCF service as window service. But I also want to expose that service as .asmx(web service).

Is it possible to do? Is there any way to expose wcf service as .asmx(web service) but need to host in window service.

Comment: What do you mean, expose as asmx? The file extension shouldn't matter.

Comment: I think he means with the same binding and behaviour you would expect from an asmx service.

Comment: @BuhBuh: it's too early in the morning for me to read minds.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When hosted as windows service, you can set the base address of your service to any URL you want, for example:

(Assuming that you already have a class called "yourServiceClass" implementing the service contract)

```
public class ExampleWindowsService : ServiceBase
{
    public ServiceHost host = null;

    public static void Main()
    {
        ServiceBase.Run(new ExampleWindowsService());
    }

    protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
    {
        if (host != null)
        {
            host.Close();
        }
        Uri baseAddress = new Uri("http://localhost:80/yourservice.asmx");
        host = new ServiceHost(typeof(yourServiceClass), baseAddress);
        host.Open();
        Console.WriteLine("Service hosted ...");
    }
}
```

Then you can add the endpoints and behaviors you need, either programatically or by configuration file. Look [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733069.aspx) to find more info about how implement a WCF service as windows service.